# React. Why this.state does not updates correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

So, I try to run the function by condition: if I got an Error in the `catch` method.

To do this, I implement the `this.state.loginError` in component state, that will change on `true` if we got an Error. So, and after `error` - the `this.state.loginError` comese back with `true` (and this is also I saw in console.log), but after state changes - my function `loginError(target)` does not want to start anyway.

See my code and logs below, please:

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false,
            loginError: false,
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', userLogin, {withCredentials: true})
            .catch(err => {
                    this.setState({
                        loginError: true
                    });
                    console.log(this.state.loginError);  // gives `true`
            });

            if (this.state.loginError) {
                console.log('Error!') //does not work
                loginError(target);
            }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `axios.post` is asyc function, and at first fires your `if` condition, and after `.catch` hook. For fix this try to replace your condition in other place, for example in `componentDidUpdate method`.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
 if (this.state.loginError) {
    console.log('Error!') //does not work
    loginError(target);
    this.setState({ loginError: false });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_functio

You are basically trying to check the state when the error is still not caught, and hence the state has not changed.

If you move your code to the render method you will see that it will works since it will re-render after the state changes. Or you get the state change withing the `componentDidUpdate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Promises instead, which is very clear and simple way around.

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false,
            loginError: false,
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        return new Promise(resolve, reject){
        axios.post('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', userLogin, {withCredentials: true})
            .catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
            })
            .then(result => resolve(result));
        }

        //Else where in Your component use this promise, where ever you call it..

        handleSubmit().then(// success code).error(// error code)
    };
```

Comment: The excess promise makes no sense - the imporant part is just the then below. It's called "the explicit construction antipattern"

Answer (score 0):

Because `axios.post` returns a promise, all code you'll write after it will be executed before the `.then()` or `.catch()` statements. If your need is to call `loginError()` function when the request fails you can call it in `.catch` statement :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', userLogin, {withCredentials: true})
    .catch(err => {
         loginError(target);
    });
```

If you need your function to be executed after updating the state you can use the `setState` callback (second argument) :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', userLogin, {withCredentials: true})
    .catch(err => {
         this.setState({ loginError: true }, () => { loginError(target); })
    });
```